# Mount external SD-card for the secondary user

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, sd-card, mount, multi-user

When I create a new user on my Asus MemMO Pad 10 (in addition to the existing primary user), the new user does not "see" the external SD card (I've tried a 64gb Micro-SDXC/exFAT and a 2gb Micro-SD/FAT32). When I switch to the primary user, "Preparing an external device" is displayed at the top of the screen and the SD card becomes "visible" as "external device".

I.e. external SD card is not automatically mounted to the secondary user, only for primary one.

Is this a feature of the Android system or ASUS tablets only? How can I make my Micro-SD card mount for the secondary user? (In case I need root access, I would consider installing it)

Device: ASUS MeMO Pad 10 [(ME102A)](http://www.asus.com/Tablets_Mobile/ASUS_MeMO_Pad_10_ME102A/), Android 4.2.2, root access not installed.

---

*Sorry for my English*

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some people wrote in 2013 that this is impossible, or at least was impossible back then. Here is what I found on a SonyMobile forum:

"Each user gets their own [internal] space and only the owner has access to the external SD-card."

"One of the reasons for not sharing the SD card is security: FAT file system doesn't allow even for the basic Linux type permissions, thus it's impossible to secure a user's files. I agree it's a bummer but they [Google] have to go w/ the most secure of the solutions..."

([Link to the SonyMobile forum](https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-Tablet-Z/Multiple-Users-and-SD-card/td-p/358194))